# Java verify Certificate is associated with a Key

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, jce

I have a Certificate and a PrivateKey that I've received from different places. Given just these two abstract objects, can I verify that the Certificate is associated with, or is the Certificate for the given PrivateKey?

I understand if these are for RSA keys, I can cast them to RsaPublicKey / RsaPrivateKey and verify that the exponent and modulus match, but what if they are ECDSA? What about other types?

I eventually want to store the Key into a a Keystore with the Certificate as its certificate chain and I expected this to throw an exception or cause some sort of error if I tried loading a key with a certificate from another key. But it doesn't seem to matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to be sure, you can sign random block of data with your private key and verify it with a public key. The public key is a part of the certificate. It works for all signature algorithms.

It is also very common that a private key structure contains the matching public key. You should check it - searching a matching key will be easier then.

Comment: I think this will work for us. I don't necessarily know what key type I have before hand but I can just try an RSA Signature verification followed by an ECDSA. If either works, I'll consider them a valid pair.

Answer (score -2):

You ***shouldn't have*** the private key. It's private. All you need is their *public* key, then you verify the certificate with that via Certificate.verify(PublicKey key).

Whoever gave the private key to you has just **FATALLY COMPROMISED** their security. They need to create a new private key, signed certificate, etc, and deploy it, and cease all use of the prior key. They also need to keep the new private key *private.*

Comment: How can you be sure from the what the OP said that it isn't *his* private key as opposed to someone elses?

Comment: @GregS because he said (a) that he 'received' them and (b) that he 'received [them] from different places'.

Comment: I mean that in some cases I will have a single file that contains the certificate and a single file that contains the private key. I am mostly concerned with giving the user an error if they have already loaded a private key and attempt to load a certificate for a different key. Or vice versa.

Comment: @tal you'll have to explain that. Are you implementing a CA application?

Comment: @ejp I will admit that I'm probably thinking about this the wrong way. We are eventually using the private key/certificate to create CMS signedData blocks. The problem is that we can't guarantee that we're getting the user's private key and certificate at the same time in the same file or bundle. Furthermore the certificate could be on different media than the private key so it could take some time to find and load the other after the first is loaded. So we are not requiring the user to load both at the same time and would like to add a check when they do that what they have loaded is correct.

Comment: @EJP: This was posted as an answer, but it does not answer the question. It should possibly be a great comment.

Comment: @John I disagree. It answers the question by telling him not to do that.

Comment: @tal The user needs to supply the signing data in one step, otherwise you have a feasibililty problem that really isn't worth solving. Ideally the signing should be done by the user with e.g. an applet that can access his private key where it already is, with his consent (e.g. a password or a PIN into his HSM). Shipping private keys around is contrary to every tenet of PKU.

Comment: @tal: given the original question (which is really a rather basic question regarding crypto) I would seriously consider getting some expert advise if this is an important part of your system. I think the question and the answer *are* valid, but I'm not so sure your system itself is safe.

Comment: @owlstead I'm aware my requirements are unique. Thanks for your constructive feedback

Comment: @tal the question here is whether your requirements even make sense and also whether they can be securely implemented. Breaking security to implement a security solution isn't actually an option.

Comment: This is not an answer but just a bunch of assumptions and a lecture.

Comment: @SanP It is a bunch of valid inferences from the information supplied: and sometimes the answer is 'you're doing it wrong'.